Is there a way to place a dictionary value into a variable defined by the users' input()?
Can someone please help me with the following solution? I’m relatively new to programming and I don’t seem to get what I’m doing wrong.
I have found too many dictionary functions and I am really struggling with this. My code give me Key-Error upon Key-Error and when I finally manage to run the program it returns “None” or 0.
Here is an example of the code.
# Dictionary called choices.
choices = {
    '1.': 'One',
    '2.': 'Two',
    '3.': 'Three',
}

# Display the choices to the user.
for k, v in choices.items():
    print(f'{k} {v}')

# Ask the user to make a choice from the dictionary options.
my_choice = int(input('Choose a number 1, 2 or 3: '))

# Make the choice the same as the index[number] of the dictionary
my_choice -= 1


# From here I get stuck
print(f'You have chosen {choices.get(str(my_choice))}.')     # This returns a 0 or None


# The desired output is

You have chosen Two.

I have tried the following options to assign dictionary items to the my_choice variable:
for loops 
dict.values()
dict .get()
dict.items()
new_choice = str(my_choice)

# The desired output is

You have chosen Two.


Maybe don't include the . in your dictionary keys.

The quotes in your code snippet are all wrong. Remember to turn off "Smart Quotes" when pasting code.

Dicts are accessed by key, not by index as you seem to suppose. I strongly recommend you to follow a good, well structured tutorial that would have helped you by making this clear.

There's no reason to use my_choice; your (intended) keys are already '1', '2', and '3', not '0', '1', and '2'.

Since your dictionary keys end with ., you need to add that to the user's input so it will match. choices.get(f'{my_choice}.'))
print(f"You have chosen {choices.get(str(my_choice) + '.')}.")

Alternately you could just use integers as the keys.
choices = {
    1: 'One',
    2: 'Two',
    3: 'Three',
}

and then
print(f"You have chosen {choices.get(my_choice)}.")

